# Let $n = {1,2,3, ...}$, prove that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is bounded above.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that the sequence tends to $e \approx 2.718281828...$, but I am having a hard time proving it. Does anyone have any hints for me?

Comment: $n \ln(1 + \frac 1 n) = n (\frac 1 n + O(\frac 1 {n^2})) \to 1$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $p=1,2,\cdots, n$, we have $(1-\frac{p}{n})<1$, and $2^{p-1}\le p!$, so $\frac{1}{p!}\le \frac{1}{2^{p-1}}$.

Therefore, if $n>1$, apply binomial theorem to $e_n$, which gives us

$$\begin{align}
e_n &= \left(1+\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\\
&= 1+1+\frac{1}{2!}(1-\frac{1}{n})+\frac{1}{3!}(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})\cdots (1-\frac{n-1}{n})
\end{align}$$
 and use above two inequalities, we have $$2<e_n<1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=3-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}<3$$

Hence $e_n$ is bounded above.

Comment: Excellent job!!

Answer (score 3):

For an integer $k\geq 0$ by [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) $$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-k}=\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^k\geq 1-\frac{k}{n+1}.$$ In particular for $k=\lceil n/2 \rceil\leq (n+1)/2$ we have $$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{-k} \geq \tfrac12$$ and by inverting both sides $$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^k \leq 2.$$ Now $n\leq 2k$ and so $$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\leq \left(1+\frac1n\right)^{2k} \leq 2^2=4.$$